# Tensorflow, how to compute broadcast product of 2 gradients?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to compute a matrix `H` as follows:

[image: Fucntion]

Where `L` is a tensor of shape `(?,N)` and `z` is a variable vector shape `(M)`.
Each element of `H` is a broadcast product of 2 gradients of `L` which respect to two elements of vector `z`.
The `tf.gradients(L,z[i]) * tf.gradients(L,z[j])` does not work because it returns a product of two sum, while I need a sum of wise products. Anyone have done that before, please help me.